# Custom Meta Box Save_Post Callback not triggered in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, post, save, meta-boxes

child Theme, functions.php, I am creating a metabox. I have two text fields in a custom metabox. I need to save the fields anytime user clicks "update" or "publish" from the admin Add post. This meta box is allowed to appear in ally types of posts, including custom posts.

I am running PHP7.3, running wordpress 5.3

I have tried to:
1) use others hooks like save_edit_post, admin_init, publish_post, etc.

2) to provide priority value to the add_Action

3) Reviewed HTTP post request to confirm the meta key-value pairs are getting passed - **yes it is.**

4) used get_post_meta() and $POST global variable to test if values are coming through - **but couldn't verify.**

```
function add_taddressbox_address_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'taddressbox_address_meta_box', // $id
        'taddressbox Address', // $title
        'show_taddressbox_address_meta_box', // $callback
        get_current_screen(), // $screen
        'normal', // $context
        'high' // $priority
    );
}

function taddressbox_address_save_postdata($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    //if this is post revision, then bail
   if (wp_is_post_revision( $post_id))
   {
       return;
   }

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail  
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;  


  $lat_val = sanitize_text_field(get_post_meta($post_id, '_taddressbox_lng', true));
    //get_post_meta($post->ID, 'taddressbox_lat', true);
    $lng_val = sanitize_text_field(get_post_meta($post_id, '_taddressbox_lng', true));
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_taddressbox_lat', $lat_val);   
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_taddressbox_lng', $lng_val);


}



function show_taddressbox_address_meta_box() {
    global $post;  

//   $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $lat = isset( $values['taddressbox_lat'] ) ? trim(esc_attr( $values['taddressbox_lat'][0] )) : '30'; 
    $lng = isset( $values['taddressbox_lng'] ) ? trim(esc_attr( $values['taddressbox_lng'][0] )) : '69';

//$lat = '30';
//$lng ='69';
    //  $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'taddressbox_address', true );
        ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="taddressbox_address_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( basename(__FILE__) ); ?>">

    <!-- All fields will go here -->

    <div id="map" tabindex="0" style="position: relative;height:400px;margin:0; padding:0; display: block;"></div>
    <div id="taddressbox_latlng">
     <label for"latitude">Latitude</label> <input type="text" id="taddressbox_lat" name="taddressbox_lat" value="<?php echo $lat; ?>">
      <label for"longitude">Longitude</label> <input type="text" id="taddressbox_lng" name ="taddressbox_lng" value="<?php echo $lng; ?>">
    </div>

<script>


<?php if ( trim($lat) == '' || trim($lng) =='' ) { ?> InitializetaddressboxMap();
<?php  } else {  ?>
InitializetaddressboxMap(<?php echo $lat; ?>,<?php echo $lng; ?>);    
<?php } ?>
</script>
    <?php  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$_POST[]` to catch and save the form submitted code. I've fixed your code, feel free to use it.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_taddressbox_address_meta_box' );

    function add_taddressbox_address_meta_box() {
        add_meta_box(
            'taddressbox_address_meta_box', // $id
            'taddressbox Address', // $title
            'show_taddressbox_address_meta_box', // $callback
            get_current_screen(), // $screen
            'normal', // $context
            'high' // $priority
        );
    }


    add_action( 'save_post', 'taddressbox_address_save_postdata' );
    function taddressbox_address_save_postdata( $post_id )
    {
        //if this is post revision, then bail
       if (wp_is_post_revision( $post_id))
       {
           return;
       }

        // if our current user can't edit this post, bail  
        if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;  

        if ( ! isset( $_POST['my_lat_lang_box_nonce'] ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        $nonce = $_POST['my_lat_lang_box_nonce'];

        // Verify that the nonce is valid.
        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my_lat_lang_box' ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        $lat_val = sanitize_text_field($_POST['taddressbox_lat']);
        $lng_val = sanitize_text_field($_POST['taddressbox_lng']);

        update_post_meta($post_id, '_taddressbox_lat', $lat_val);   
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_taddressbox_lng', $lng_val);


    }



    function show_taddressbox_address_meta_box( $post ) {

        $lat = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_taddressbox_lat', true );
        $lng = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_taddressbox_lng', true );


        wp_nonce_field( 'my_lat_lang_box', 'my_lat_lang_box_nonce' );

         ?>


        <!-- All fields will go here -->

        <div id="map" tabindex="0" style="position: relative;height:400px;margin:0; padding:0; display: block;"></div>
        <div id="taddressbox_latlng">
         <label for"latitude">Latitude</label> <input type="text" id="taddressbox_lat" name="taddressbox_lat" value="<?php echo $lat; ?>">
          <label for"longitude">Longitude</label> <input type="text" id="taddressbox_lng" name ="taddressbox_lng" value="<?php echo $lng; ?>">
        </div>

    <script>


    <?php if ( trim($lat) == '' || trim($lng) =='' ) { ?> InitializetaddressboxMap();
    <?php  } else {  ?>
    InitializetaddressboxMap(<?php echo $lat; ?>,<?php echo $lng; ?>);    
    <?php } ?>
    </script>
        <?php  }
```

Comment: Thanks. That maybe have been one of the issues, but just using $_POST didn't fix the issue.

It turns out, sanitize_text_field() was stripping out the values and therefore nothing was being saved - this was the main culprit. When, I removed the sanitize_text_field, I am now able to save the values. Now, I need to run it through custom sanitation probably.

Comment: I had tested the code I wrote and it was saving the data perfectly, assuming that you're return values are just numbers sanitize_text_field should work properly. 
Let me know what data you are expecting and maybe I can help you more.

Comment: The text should would only contain floating point numbers (negative or positive). It seemed like sanitize_text_field actually returned an empty value. It works now. Thank you so much!